# Powershell command Register-PSRepository ends in error

Tags: powershell, jfrog-cli

I am getting error while running the following snippet:

```
if((Get-PSRepository -Name $artifactory.Key.ToString().Trim()) -eq $null)
{
    #register the repository if not found
    $Location = "$($ConfigInfo.ArtifactoryCredentials.ArtifactoryServer.ToString().Trim())/$($artifactory.Value.ToString().Trim())"

    Write-Host "Registering repositories $($Location)" -ForegroundColor Cyan

    Register-PSRepository -Name $artifactory.Key.ToString().Trim() -SourceLocation $Location `
                                                                   -PublishLocation $Location `
                                                                   -InstallationPolicy Trusted -Verbose
}
```

And the error that I am getting is:

```
Register-PSRepository : The specified Uri '....' for parameter 'SourceLocation' is an invalid Web Uri. Please ensure that it meets the Web Uri requirements.
```

It is already checked that the Url is valid. 
It seems that it is already discussed here and still an open issue and has been sitting in limbo for quite a while

[See this issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet/issues/317)

I was wondering if there is workaround and your input will be valuable. I basically need to iterate the JFrog repository contents, publish nuget artifacts and wanted to do it by the following:
[Jfrog Powershell](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-work-with-powershell-modules-and-nuget-repository-in-artifactory/)

Now I am pondering the following option and it would be great to have your feedback:

1. Download & install the jfrog cli
2. Call jfrog commands from powershell to operate on the artifactory with artifacts.

Comment: The error surrounds the `$Location` URL. It's hard to provide advice without it. I am guessing that you shouldn't include the credentials in the `-SourceLocation` URL may be causing the issue?

Comment: there is no credential information fed into the -SourceLocation

Comment: I was just wondering because `$Location` had `...ArtifactoryCredentials...` in the string. So I was wondering about what the final URL looked like.